# What is the best way to process large amount of network packets in Python?

Tags: python, data-processing

I'm doing a research in malware detection systems. To make a model of infected systems behavior I need to process a large amount of packets from a Pcap file, group them in flows (packets with the same IPs a ports of source and destiny) and then extract some features from those flows.

I'm using DPKT to parse and read the info from the packets. My question is about the most efficient way to do the grouping process. I have begun using a PostgreSQL database, querying if a flow with the info of the package exists, and adding it to the flow or creating a new one. But I think this method is very inefficient, so I'm asking for other alternatives like using in-memory structures, improve the database or any other thing.

Comment: how much data is it? (lines/filesize)

Comment: the Pcap files could have from 10K lines to a few millions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data fits into memory, then pythons [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) data structure seems very efficient, especially speed wise.

One way to solve your problem could be to use the `Counter` class which is a subclass of dict:

```
from collections import Counter
grouped = Counter()

with open('packets.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        src_ip, src_port, dst_ip, dst_port = ... # extract the ip address
        key = "{}--{}--{}--{}".format(src_ip, src_port, dst_ip, dest_port)
        grouped[key] += 1

most_common_combinations = grouped.most_common()
```

Comment: thank you for the reply. I think the problem is a bit more complex because the flows are defined by 4 fields: IP src, IP dest, port src and port dest. In addition, I'm not sure about use data in memory because the Pcap files could have millions of packets

Comment: ah, so you group by many fields at once? How would you do that? Or are you looking for some sort of clustering algorithm?

Comment: Yes, I need to group the packages that have the same values in those fields, and I am asking for alternatives to do that because what I'm doing now is: I created a table called "flow", and then for every package I check in the table if it already exists a flow with the IP src, IP dest, port src and port dest equal to those fields in the package: if answer if 'yes', I increment de column numPackages of this register (this flow); if answer is 'no', I create a new register (a new flow) with those values and with nunPackages equal to 1

Comment: I forgot to say that, in addition to those fields that I extract (IPs, ports and numPackages) y extract others features (as timestamps and total size of packages) in order to do some ML classification

Comment: @p0kero, alright, you check for *all* the keys at once. I've updated my source code now to reflect that

Comment: if you'd like to do those things in memory, that's the way you'd attack that. You only hold the keys and counts in memory, so give it a shot to see if you'd exceed RAM or not

Comment: okey, I'm going to do some test with this approach in order to check if it's viable ;)